# I'm stumped trying to access data from a web page in software

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, indy10

I'm using Indy 10 in Delphi 7 to attempt to access some data from a hardware device on our local network, but accessing the HTML page using `TIdHTML.Get()` only returns the base code and not the page that is displayed by browsers.

I've saved the HTML and JS files to a web server so you can look at them.  Also includes a screen shot of what it looks like in a browser.

https://stationplaylist.com/temp/stl_status.html

https://stationplaylist.com/temp/stl_status.js

https://stationplaylist.com/temp/stl_status.jpg

I just want to know if the Incoming Stream Status is ON or OFF, but no idea how to access it.  I hope it is possible somehow using Indy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that *downloading* is one thing (which you do with Indy10) and *interpreting* the download(s) is another (which your internet browser does). A short journey into what your web browser does:

- Parsing the downloaded **stl_status.html**, discovering HTML elements with attributes like `src=` which implies to download those files, too.
- From the HTML page you can see that in **stl_status.js** the function `afterLoad()` is called, which indirectly executes `get_Status()`, which calls `loadDoc('/stl_data.html')` (oh wait, isn't that a file we yet haven't looked at?), which (of course) does a HTTP call itself to just download that file.

Most likely you don't need to go that way, but can download **stl_data.html** directly and process it as per its layout (the JS file's code should be easy to understand for you).

I repeat: downloading files does not imply rendering a website.

Comment: I didn't notice the /stl_data.html, and it does contain exactly what I need in a colon separated values format. Problem solved. Many thanks for that.